# Strange rotation in C# graphics

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I am using OnPaint method in my class Class1 : Panel.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    Graphics g = e.Graphics; 
}
```

to rotate and draw rectangle I am using

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.RotateAt(90, rotationPoint);
g.Transform = m;
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, rectangle)
```

the problem is, that rotation isn't working as I want it to.

[image: http://i52.tinypic.com/2rca2ic.png]

Red square is rotation point and it's located in the middle-top of rectangle. How to set x, y and rotation point so rotation would work properly?

After rotating at 90 degress it should look like this

[image: i53.tinypic.com/2co25wj.png]

red pixel is still at the same location.

Comment: So, what *does* it look like after rotation?

Comment: Like Marcelo said... and how are you setting rotationPoint?

Comment: After rotation red point is outside the rectangle. I am setting rotation point as  new PointF(x-(rectangleWidth/2), y) where x and y are coordinates of red pixel

Comment: What's interesting there is also another issue. When I am using 1 pixel width rectangle and do 180 rotation then rotated one is 1 pixel to the left of original one ;)

Comment: You should set rotation point to new PointF(rectangleWidth/2, rectangleHeight/2); no x and y should be involved.

Comment: after setting rotation point to what you said the rectangle has just disappeared ;)

Answer (score 1):

*Rotation point* is not the point, which you want to rotate. It is point, **around which** graphics is rotated. So if you draw a rectangle on the top of the graphics and want to rotate it (rectangle) - then you should set rotation point as **center of graphics** and rotate image to 90 degrees.

Here is example, that does almost what you want:

```
base.OnPaint(e);

var g = e.Graphics;
var width = g.VisibleClipBounds.Width;
var height = g.VisibleClipBounds.Height;
var rotationPoint = new PointF(width / 2, height / 2); ;

// draw center point
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new RectangleF(rotationPoint.X - 5, rotationPoint.Y - 5, 10, 10));

using (var path = new GraphicsPath())
{
    var rectangle = new RectangleF((width - 10) / 2, 0, 10, 10);
    var m = new Matrix();
    m.RotateAt(90, rotationPoint);
    path.AddRectangle(rectangle);
    path.Transform(m);

    // draw rotated point
    g.FillPath(Brushes.Black, path);
}
```

Comment: I used your solution and here's the picture of what I've accomplished: http://i52.tinypic.com/2j47rrl.png Lower rectangle has 0 rotation and is drawn in the center, upper drawn in the center and 180 rotation. Upper is one pixel to the left the lower one.